# tastypie: how to add permissions to a user?

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm building a IOS app with django-tastypie. The default permission of a user is only "get" something. However, a user can be granted the "add" permission to post something. how to design the  api of tastypie? how to grant permissions to a user using django-tastypi?

Answer (score 1):

First I'd like to point out the nuance between authentication and authorization that tripped me up when using tastypie before:

- **Authentication** means "Prove to me that you are who you claim to be" - i.e. some form of password login or API key
- **Authorization** means "Now that I know who you are, let me check what kind of privileges you have - i.e. let me look at what user group you belong to / what specific rights are granted for your user account, etc.

Now, with that in mind, take a look at the [very conise examples here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication_authorization.html#authentication-authorization) if you haven't already.

For example, this is how you might restrict users to only be able to access their own user information:

```
# REST endpoint for authenticating user accounts
class UserResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'auth/user'
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()

    def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
        return object_list.filter(username=request.user)
```

And here's a snippet of how you might authenticate a user while interacting with a view:

```
# first check that the user is allowed to post
username = form.cleaned_data['username']
password = form.cleaned_data['password'] # @todo: remove this for production
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is None:
    raise Http404('Error: new_frame: invalid username / password')
if not user.is_active:
    raise Http404('Error: new_frame: your account is inactive')
# username / password is correct + user is active, proceed with posting
```

Comment: I'm using DjangoAuthorization(), but for example, how to add a add_message permission a user?